# $\sigma(\delta)_{A}=\sigma(\delta_{A})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A\subset X$ a non-empty set, $\emptyset\not=\delta\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\delta_{A}:=\{A\cap B: B \in \delta$}.
Si $\sigma(\delta_{A})$ is is the σ-algebra in $A$ generated by $\delta_{A}$, proof that $\sigma(\delta)_{A}=\sigma(\delta_{A})$

since $ A\cap B\subset B \in \delta$ then $A \cap B \in \delta$, this shows that $\delta_{A} \subset \delta$ then $\sigma(\delta_{A})\subset \sigma(\delta)_{A}$

I have tried to demonstrate the other restraint without success. Which way do you advise me to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for the inclusion $\sigma (\delta _A)\subset \sigma (\delta )_A$ is not correct. Take for example $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\delta =\{1,2\}$. Then $\{1\}\subset \{1,2\}\in \sigma (\delta )$, but $\{1\}\notin \sigma (\delta )$.

The way to proceed is the following. You have that $$\sigma (\delta )_A=\{A\cap B\mid B\in \sigma (\delta )\}.$$ In particular, it's a $\sigma -$algebra that contains $\delta _A$. Therefore $\sigma (\delta _A)\subset \sigma (\delta )_A$. For the converse inclusion, let $$\mathcal S:=\{S\in \mathcal P(X)\mid A\cap S\in \sigma (\delta _A)\}.$$

Then $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma -$algebra that contains $\delta $. Therefore, $\sigma (\delta )\subset \mathcal S$, and thus $\sigma (\delta )_A\subset \sigma (\delta _A)$.

Comment: why $\mathcal S$  contains $\delta$ ?

Comment: because if $B\in \delta $, then $B\cap A\in \sigma (\delta _A)$ @TheMartian

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{B\in \sigma(\delta): B \cap A \in \sigma(\delta_A)\}$. Verify that it is a sigma algebra and that it contains $\delta$. Hence, it contains $\sigma(\delta)$. This is what you want to prove.

Comment: @Surb Yes, that was  a typo. Thanks for pointing out.